# A mathematical expression for "grid search"?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, searching, multigrid

I've got a question whether there is a mathematical expression for a grid search? I have two parameters *a* and *b* in [0;1]. Depending on the values of *a* and *b*, I get a value for my function (the value is called *MAPE* for *Mean Absolute Percentage Error*).

What I do is the following: Let *a* run from 0.1, 0.2, ... , 0.9 and *b* from 0.1, 0.2, ..., 0.9, I get 81 different MAPE values for each combination of *a* and *b*. The "optimal" value for *a* and *b* is those where the MAPE value is the lowest of the computed 81 different values. My question is: *How can this grid search expressed mathematically?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for [arg min](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max).

Let $f$ be your function that gives you the MAPE based on $a$ and $b$, and let $S = \{0.1, 0.2, ... , 0.9\}$. Then you are computing $$\text{arg min}_{a,b \in S} f(a,b),$$

where $\text{arg min}_{a,b \in S} f(a,b)$ is defined as

$$ \left\{ (a,b) \in S \; | \; \forall \; (x,y) \in S: f(a,b) \le f(x,y) \right\}.$$

Not that the result is a set of pairs, since there may be many minimal pairs.